# Nested arrays in ini file

Tags: php

I am trying to have a nested array structure inside an ini settings file. The structure i have is:

```
stuct1[123][a] = "1"
stuct1[123][b] = "2"
stuct1[123][c] = "3"
stuct1[123][d] = "4"
```

But this doesnt work. Can anyone explain if this type of structure is possible with `parse_ini_file`

If it is possible, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you read the docs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

INI files are pretty limited and parse_ini_file is far from perfect. If you have requirements like this, you should better look for some other syntax.

What about [JSON](http://json.org/)? It's [support in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) comes with almost same comfort:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), TRUE);
file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: It should be added that ini files are supposed to be human writeable and machine readable. JSON files are supposed to be machine writeable and human readable.
They are very strict in terms of syntax, tiny errors will render the whole json file invalid.
Almost no error in an ini file will render the file invalid, only the line.

Comment: All one needs to do is [section] and arraykey[0] the entries. The methods suggested work in at least PHP >=5.6 and satisfy the needs by using the parse_ini_file function. While it doesn't support complex multi-dimensional arrays, it will support nested arrays (along with additional non-array data). Since PHP allows pulling an array out of an array really easily. , it also supports sub-Solution to problem above is adding the section header and using it to create the outer array.

Answer (score 50):

You can use the [sections feature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#example-2355) of `parse_ini_file` for this task.

Be sure to set your second parameter to `true`:

```
parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
```

It's not exactly possible to make sub sections but you can make an indexed sub array like this:

```
[123]
setting[] = "1"
setting[] = "2"
setting[] = "3"
setting[] = "4"
```

Parsed it would look similar like thos

```
[123][setting][0] => "1"
[123][setting][1] => "2"
[123][setting][2] => "3"
[123][setting][3] => "4"
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it exactly addresses the question and is not an alternative solution

Comment: Actually, it is possible to do (or at least simulate) sub sections, by simply including an array in an array, then referencing that by the nested array's name.

Answer (score 17):

You can create a hard maximum of three levels.

```php
<?php

define('BIRD', 'Dodo bird');

$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($ini_array,true).'</pre>';

?>
```

parse_ini_file.ini

```
; This is a sample configuration file
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini

[first_section]
one = 1
five = 5
animal = BIRD

[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"
second_section[one] = "1 associated"
second_section[two] = "2 associated"
second_section[] = "1 unassociated"
second_section[] = "2 unassociated"

[third_section]
phpversion[] = "5.0"
phpversion[] = "5.1"
phpversion[] = "5.2"
phpversion[] = "5.3"
```

Output

```
Array (

    [first_section] => Array (
        [one] => 1
        [five] => 5
        [animal] => Dodo bird
    )

    [second_section] => Array (
        [path] => /usr/local/bin
        [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
        [second_section] => Array (
            [one] => 1 associated
            [two] => 2 associated
            [0] => 1 unassociated
            [1] => 2 unassociated
        )
    )

    [third_section] => Array (
        [phpversion] => Array (
            [0] => 5.0
            [1] => 5.1
            [2] => 5.2
            [3] => 5.3
        )
    )
    
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me as it shows how much levels can you use and also confirms that named keys are allowed (I didn't knew about that)

Comment: I believe you meant to say "*maximum* of three levels".

Comment: @DeanHouseholder  I think likely maximum, but know it is possible to create at least a minimum of three levels.

Comment: No, I meant to say a hard maximum of three levels. Your second and third section examples show the maximum. The ini file spec doesn't allow any more.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is another way to group values in the ini:
>
> my.ini:
>
> ```
> [singles] 
> test = a test 
> test2 = another test 
> test3 = this is a test too
>
> [multiples] 
> tests[] = a test 
> tests[] = another 
> test tests[] = this is a test too
> ```
>
> my.php:
>
> The same as:
>
> ```
> <?php 
> $init['test'] = 'a test';
> $init['test2'] = 'another test';
> $init['test3'] = 'this is a test too';
> $init['tests'][0] = 'a test';
> $init['tests'][1] = 'another test';
> $init['tests'][2] = 'this is a
> test too'; ?>
> ```
>
> This works with the bool set to true also, can be useful with loops.
>   Works with the bool set to true as well.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Posted by david dot dyess at gmail dot com 4 years ago