# php read nested sections in ini file

Tags: php, nested, ini

I try to read the file names.ini below
into a php array and then access certain
repeating sections within the code.

My code does not work correct, the base
problem seems to be, that ini files don't
have a structure to nest sections.

But: could there be  a workaround if
the code would be slightly modified???

File names.ini:

```
[baseSetup]

  sections[] = name
  sections[] = place

[name][1]
  DummyName1
[name][2]
  DummyName2
[name][3]
  DummyName3

[place][]
New York
[place][]
Texas
[place][]
San Francisco
```

Php-script to read the file:

```
<?php
   $setup =  parse_ini_file("names.ini",true);
   print_r($setup);
   echo("<br/> ---------------<br/>");
   
   echo ("setup[name = " . $setup["name"] . "<br/>");
   print_r($setup["name"]);
   echo ("<br/><br/>");

   foreach ($setup["baseSetup"] as $key => $val) {
     echo ("key: $key:<br/>");
     print_r($val);
     
     foreach($val as $idx) {
     
       echo ("<br/>count of $idx: " . count($setup[$idx]) . "<br/>");
     
     }     
     echo ("<br/>");
     
   }
    
?>
```

Further specification:

I could write it this way:

```
[baseSetup]
  nSections = 2
  
[sections] 
  name = 3
  place = 4
  
[name1] 
content = DummyName1
 
[name2]  
content = DummyName2

[name3]  
content = DummyName3      

[place1]  
content = New York
[place2]  
content = Texas
[place3]  
content= San Francisco
[place4]  
content= Boston
```

And read it like this:

```
 <?php
   $setup =  parse_ini_file("names2.ini",true);
   
   print_r($setup);
   echo("<br/> ---------------<br/>");
   
   $nNames = $setup["sections"]["name"];
   $nPlaces = $setup["sections"]["place"];
   
   for ($i=1;$i<=$nNames;$i++) {
     $key = "name".$i;
     echo ("name = "); print_r($setup[$key]); echo("<br/>");
   }

   for ($i=1;$i<=$nPlaces;$i++) {
     $key = "place".$i;       
     echo ("place = "); print_r($setup[$key]); echo("<br/>");
   }
    

?>
```

So this would work as a basis.
But it would like to access the names and places
without having to explicitly name their number in the ini file.

Comment: What do you expect from your code & data sample? What is the error you are actually facing? What is your debug trace?

Comment: You have very weird ini file format. It should consist of sections and key/value pairs

Comment: I did edit the question. Maybe this is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore: I would like to add sections insetad of strings; e.g. instead of "New York" 
I would like to have 
[City] 
  name = New York 
  citizens =  8,335,897

Comment: There is a related question for this topic:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614866/nested-arrays-in-ini-file
I started with this configuration. But I could not manage to
access the array elements individually (in the question there also 
is only a print_r to show that the nesting of sections is possible, 
but not an example for access the elements).